# popunder javascript appears on 1 time , want to appear 3 time per visit

Tags: javascript

i am using popunder.net
i am inserting popunder while clickling on video
after 1 popunder script doesnot show more on click( to start video)
i want to make it 3 times

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">
            /*<![CDATA[/* */
              var _pop = _pop || [];
              _pop.push(['siteId', 3374191]);
              _pop.push(['minBid', 0]);
              _pop.push(['popundersPerIP', 0]);
              _pop.push(['delayBetween', 0]);
              _pop.push(['default', false]);
              _pop.push(['defaultPerDay', 0]);
              _pop.push(['topmostLayer', false]);
              (function() {
                var pa = document.createElement('script'); pa.type = 'text/javascript'; pa.async = true;
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                pa.src = '//c1.popads.net/pop.js';
                pa.onerror = function() {
                  var sa = document.createElement('script'); sa.type = 'text/javascript'; sa.async = true;
                  sa.src = '//c2.popads.net/pop.js';
                  s.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, s);
                };
                s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa, s);
              })();
            /*]]>/* */
            </script>
```

Comment: Just looked it up and it is an ad network. Before attempting this, make sure you check the terms before doing: they may forbid this sort of thing leading to them maybe retaining payouts, dropping your account, whatever. As far as the behavior goes, it doesn’t look like you’re managing the actual click behavior. If you were, create a counter variable and on each render, increment the counter and then wrap the render behavior in a counter < 3 check,

Comment: thank its okay with terms , can u give me example how to implement counter here? i am new at javascript